# Spinner onItemSelected called indefinitely

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a Spinner and I am changing the entries on every item click using setAdapter. The issue I am facing is that on click of spinner the setOnItemSelectedListener is being called indefinite times. You can see in the below code that a confirmation box is to be shown on click of every item and that dialog box just keeps appearing infinite number of times.
Below is my code

```
adapter_after_confirm = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.spinner_after_confirmation,       android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter_after_waiting = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.spinner_after_waiting, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter_after_boarded = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.spinner_after_boarded, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter_after_reached = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.spinner_after_reached, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter_after_confirm.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
adapter_after_waiting.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
adapter_after_boarded.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
adapter_after_reached.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            if(spinnerSelected){
                if(selected.equals("Waiting For Cab")){
                    confirmDialog("Waiting For Cab");
                    spinnerStatusChange.setAdapter(adapter_after_waiting);
                }

                else if(selected.equals("Boarded Cab")){
                    confirmDialog("Boarded Cab");
                    spinnerStatusChange.setAdapter(adapter_after_boarded);
                }

                else if(selected.equals("Reached Destination")){
                    confirmDialog("Boarded Cab");
                    spinnerStatusChange.setAdapter(adapter_after_reached);
                    spinnerStatusChange.setEnabled(false);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Location tracking is now disabled",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use "if(spinnerSelected)" because the methot only called when the spinner is selected.

Try this:

```
adapter_after_confirm = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.spinner_after_confirmation, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter_after_waiting = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.spinner_after_waiting, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter_after_boarded = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.spinner_after_boarded, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter_after_reached = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.spinner_after_reached, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears

adapter_after_confirm.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
adapter_after_waiting.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
adapter_after_boarded.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
adapter_after_reached.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            if(selected.equals("Waiting For Cab")){
                confirmDialog("Waiting For Cab");
                spinnerStatusChange.setAdapter(adapter_after_waiting);
            }

            else if(selected.equals("Boarded Cab")){
                confirmDialog("Boarded Cab");
                spinnerStatusChange.setAdapter(adapter_after_boarded);
            }

            else if(selected.equals("Reached Destination")){
                confirmDialog("Boarded Cab");
                spinnerStatusChange.setAdapter(adapter_after_reached);
                spinnerStatusChange.setEnabled(false);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Location tracking is now disabled",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


    }

});
```

Comment: on doing that the setOnItemSelectedListener is automatically called when the activity is created.

Comment: Then you can add an initial item which does nothing when it is selected. For example: "Choose Item". When activity is created the listener will be called but do nothing.